# gdb causes sem_wait() to fail with EINTR error

Tags: linux, gdb, signals, semaphore

After switching from Ubuntu to CentOS 5.4 we came across a strange GDB behavior. Running application in debugger causes `sem_wait()` to return several (5-10) times with `EINTR` error.

I installed the latest GDB version but it did not solve the problem.
I suppose this is cause by some signal sent by GDB but I could not get any info in signal handler.

Testing `errno` after `sem_wait()` and resuming waiting is not a big deal, I just wanted to know if anybody has an explanation for this phenomenon.

Comment: You are aware that you should (almost) always `while (sem_wait(&sem) == -1 && errno == EINTR) continue;`?

Comment: @ephemient Now I am. I'm just curious why I didn't have this signal on Ubuntu. What makes the difference here, is it kernel or glibc?

Comment: Does your application use `alarm()` or any other signals internally?  Running under GDB might just be changing the timing of whatever is going on.